# Sortable Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

Estou precisando montar uma tela onde arrasto opções de uma lista para outra. Contudo ao carregar da primeira para a segunda, apenas deverá ser criado uma cópia para a segunda lista.

Quando o usuário realizar o processo inverso (carregar da lista 2 pra lista 1) deverá excluir da lista 2 e não fazer nada na lista 1.

A kendo me da o exemplo a seguir, mas não consigo ajustá-lo. Pois toda vez que movo as opções de um lado para outro a primeira lista perde elementos.

Obrigada!

[Exemplo da Kendo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EnAyu/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O componente `SortableList` não possui a funcionalidade que você deseja. O melhor caminho seria construir seu próprio componente, a partir dos componentes `Draggable` e `DropTargetArea`, que também foram usados na criação do `SortableList`.

**Veja**:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/droptargetarea